# Calendar changes time when I add an item manually

Tags: calendar

I open the calendar app and click on a day. A window pops up where I type the name of the event. Out of habit, instead of pressing "edit details" I press "add" because in another app I used to use this would show a window asking for details. The issue I'm describing does not happen if you press "edit details". So what I get is an event marked as "all day". I edit it to not be all day and set up the start time (18:00) and leave the end time to its default (19:00) and press "Done". What shows up is the time 1 hour later, i.e. starting at 19:00 and ending at 20:00.

This is similar but distinct from this question, [Timezone issue Gnome calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321372/timezone-issue-gnome-calendar), since I have this issue when adding items manually. In fact in all discussion online I've seen, the issue being reported is when items are imported from other calendars or files.

On the other hand, I have in fact imported events from my google account in the past, which included events both in WEST and CEST...

Since I suppose this is a bug, let me know if I should report it somewhere.

It's the calendar app that comes preinstalled in Ubuntu and has this logo:

[image: Calendar app logo]

Also, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: The one that's just called "calendar" and comes pre-installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmmm. Unable to reproduce in my 21.04 test environment. If it was a bug in 20.04, seems like it's already been fixed.